# Display long Description in asp .net with Next Page(Page wise)

Tags: asp.net

I want to display a very long description data retrieved from the database using asp .net. That Description should be displayed in Page Wise and all the details wouldn't be seen in a single page. When user clicks on "Next Page" , that page will show the next details and so on towards the end of the total text/description.
 Is there any such control where we can show this type?

Please answer me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing data in a gridview, then select **gridview** of **design page**, go to **solution explorer** and make a change in **AllowPaging** from no to yes.